# JavaScript, jQuery - retrieving the item name in dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am trying to figure out how to get the name of the product selected `label_method: :name` as shown in the form. I can retrieve the id of the selected item as shown in the js section.

#### _form.html.erb

```
<%= f.simple_fields_for :items, wrapper: false do |builder| %>

<%= builder.input :product_id, collection: Product.all, 
    label_method: :name, value_method: :id, label: false, 
    placeholder: 'Type or select item', input_html: { :multiple => true, 
    id: 'select2-product' } %>
```

#### js

```
$("#select2-product").click(function() {
 var selectedItem = $(this);
 console.log("selectedItem " + selectedItem);
 console.log("selectedItem.val() " + selectedItem.val());
});
```

#### console output

```
 selectedItem [object Object] 
 selectedItem.val() 1
```

#### observation

`selectedItem.val()` gives the :id of the element selected in the dropdown list

`selectedItem.text()` gives all the items in the dropdown list. How would I get the one selected only? As answered by @Amir

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work, actually you need to select the `text` and not the `value`, so `text()` get you the actual text of the item

```
console.log("selectedItem.text() " + selectedItem.text());
```

**[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/HFp9D/)**

```
$('selectedItem:selected').text() for the selected text specifically
```

Comment: what if I just want to show the item selected instead of all the items in the dropdown list?

Comment: $('option:selected).text() @lightbots